# How to send message object to the API accepting Multipart file object?

Tags: java, spring-integration, multipart

I want to be able to send file to the api below, without physically creating the file

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/receiveFile", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> receiveFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
                                           ){
}
```

Using Spring Integration -

I  have below JDBC inbound channel adapater

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInbound"
                                      channel="inputChannel"
                                      data-source="dataSource"
                                      query="SELECT * FROM Products"
                                      row-mapper="productRowMapper">
                                    
        <int:poller fixed-delay="3600" time-units="SECONDS"/>
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

channel "inputChannel" does processing, and generates a row in form of a string for each product below

```
public class Product{
   String type;
   int price;
   String technology;
  // getters and setters
}

Product p = new Product();
p.setType("ABC");
p.setPrice(10000);
p.setTechnology("X");
```

Message message  = new GenericMessage(p.toString());

```
// Above message obj looks like as -> GenericMessage[payload=ABC 10000 X] and each message there is a header "fileName"
```

These messages are sent to an aggregator. The rows are grouped based on the file Name in this aggregator. The output of this is file-outbound-channel-adapter, which writes out file to a disk

instead of creating a file on disk and writing this row to it, it is possible to create a file object (but not creating a file on disk) and send this data to API above?

Another challenge is , the data is going to be polled through out the day, and at a specific time, I need send all the rows created to the API, there could be 10,000 such rows generated say between 8 AM to 8 PM. I have a rest API, which when invoked should send all these rows to the API, but as file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a file object and you cannot without a real operation system handler. You need to create a `MultiValueMap` as a payload of key which is going to be essentially a file name and your content as a value. Then a `FormHttpMessageConverter` of the `RestTemplate` will do the trick to transfer such a request to the service.

I believe same can be applied for your bulk load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use smth like this:

```
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(dataString.getBytes()) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return "file";
        }
    });

    var request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    return restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/receiveFile", request, String.class);
```